# Adding a caption to a Kable Table in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am using RMarkdown to write some university work
I have created a table using the code below and need to export it to Microsoft Word

Can anyone tell me how to add a label describing the data in the table or do I have to do this in MS Word afterwards

```
    ---
    title: "Data"
    author: "foo"
    date: "2 July 2016"
    output:
      word_document:
    bibliography: bibliography.bib
    ---

    kable(table(Rawdata$Var1, Rawdata$Var2))
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the `caption` argument in `kable`.

If you want more options for formatting tables in Word output, I would recommend downloading the `Gmisc` package and using the `Gmisc::docx_document` format. Just keep in mind that it will save the file as an HTML file that can be opened as a Word Document and preserve the formatting.

For example:

````
---
title: "Data"
author: "foo"
date: "2 July 2016"
output:  Gmisc::docx_document
---

```{r}
knitr::kable(head(mtcars[, 1:3]),
             caption = "This is the table caption")
```
````

Comment: @Braiam What if I want to make the caption bigger?